# compiling less to css from classic asp / vbscript

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, less, wsh

I'm trying to get classic asp / vbscript to run a less compiler (https://github.com/duncansmart/less.js-windows). Running the exact command from a real cmd prompt on the server works fine. So it's going to be one of those permissiony type things. My server is Win2003 x86 / IIS6.

```
<%
' foo.asp

outpath = "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\site\less"
cmd = "c:\less.js-windows-v1.6.2\lessc.cmd"
Set Shell = server.createobject("WScript.Shell")
nodeCommand = cmd & " " & outPath & "\app.less " & outPath & "\app.css"
errCode = Shell.Run(nodeCommand, 0, True)
' errcode = 1

%>
```

`foo.asp` is running somewhere on the web server, anonymously.

`cmd.exe` has had `iusr_server` added so that it has read and execute permission.

`c:\less.js-windows-v1.6.2` has had `iusr_server` added with read/execute as well.

I've granted `everyone` permission to modify files in side `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\site\less` to make sure it's not a permission thing.

I have tried modifying my command to include `CMD /C` ahead of the command file name.

Comment: Try throwing your code into a VBS file and running it on your web server, just to rule out anything code-related.

Comment: You might find this helpful [How do I execute a DOS command / batch file / exe from ASP?](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-execute-a-dos-command/batch-file/exe-from-asp.html)

Comment: @Lankymart: I've tried pretty much all that already. I know it's permission related. It seems to be that I'm running a `.cmd` file as opposed to an exe or bat. @Bond: this works fine outside IIS. It must be permission related, but I have granted IUSR exe rights on cmd.exe and the less app and the location being written to.

Comment: @frumbert If it is permissions you should be getting some `HTTP 500 Internal Server Error` useless your error pages are not configured correctly for `500-100.asp`.

Comment: @frumbert Hi, sorry to add to the "have you tried" list. But have you tried `ShellExecute`, it forces security elevation of the program. `objShell.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/k echo test", "", "runas", 1`

Comment: Did you also try the solution proposed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697924/running-vbs-script-on-server-from-iis-asp)? Looks like very similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process:

- Stop the server
- Change relative paths to full paths for all files
- Reconfigure the [IUSR](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770966) to be you
- Restart the server

Comment: They are full paths already, including the references inside the cmd files being executed. I guess I could have configured IUSR to be me since the script runs interactively it (ps you linked to doco for iis7, not iis6). Solution seems to be create a new user with the perimissions on those items and used it in place of the anonymous user ... seems like a kludge, but then again this is IIS.